# Rubberduck VBA Parser, Episode V: The ANTLR Strikes Back

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, rubberduck

I changed my mind. I don't want to implement 200-some `Node` classes. Instead, I'll be working directly with the ANTLR generated classes, to implement the Rubberduck code inspections, unit test method discovery, the "Code Explorer" tree view, and everything else Rubberduck might need a parse tree for.

The `Node` [derived classes already implemented](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/78583/23788) aren't wasted though: I'll eventually use them to expose a high-level view of the VBA code, to VBA itself (through COM interop) - that will enable very cool stuff, like VBA code that can enumerate its modules' members.

I changed the `VBParser` - I renamed `ParseInternal` to `Parse` (it becomes an overload of the public `Parse` method), and made it `public` as well:

```
public class VBParser : IRubberduckParser
{
    public INode Parse(string projectName, string componentName, string code)
    {
        var result = Parse(code);
        var walker = new ParseTreeWalker();

        var listener = new VBTreeListener(projectName, componentName);
        walker.Walk(listener, result);

        return listener.Root;
    }

    public IParseTree Parse(string code)
    {
        var input = new AntlrInputStream(code);
        var lexer = new VisualBasic6Lexer(input);
        var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new VisualBasic6Parser(tokens);

        return parser.startRule();
    }
}
```

Now I can have an ANTLR `IParseTree` wherever I need it. One place I'm going to need it, is to discover *test methods* in the active VBA project. Rubberduck test methods are always *public, parameterless methods*, so I wrote this extension method/class:

```
public static class ParseTreeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds all public procedures in specified parse tree.
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<VisualBasic6Parser.SubStmtContext> GetPublicProcedures(this IParseTree parseTree)
    {
        var walker = new ParseTreeWalker();

        var listener = new PublicSubListener();
        walker.Walk(listener, parseTree);

        return listener.Members;
    }

    private class PublicSubListener : VisualBasic6BaseListener
    {
        private readonly IList<VisualBasic6Parser.SubStmtContext> _members = new List<VisualBasic6Parser.SubStmtContext>();
        public IEnumerable<VisualBasic6Parser.SubStmtContext> Members { get { return _members; } }

        public override void EnterSubStmt(VisualBasic6Parser.SubStmtContext context)
        {
            var visibility = context.visibility();
            if (visibility == null || visibility.PUBLIC() != null)
            {
                _members.Add(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a unit test for it:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void GetPublicProceduresReturnsPublicSubs()
    {
        IRubberduckParser parser = new VBParser();
        var code = "Sub Foo()\nEnd Sub\n\nPrivate Sub FooBar()\nEnd Sub\n\nPublic Sub Bar()\nEnd Sub\n\nPublic Sub BarFoo(ByVal fb As Long)\nEnd Sub\n\nFunction GetFoo() As Bar\nEnd Function";

        var module = parser.Parse(code);
        var procedures = module.GetPublicProcedures().ToList();
        var parameterless = procedures.Where(p => p.argList().arg().Count == 0).ToList();

        Assert.AreEqual(3, procedures.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(2, parameterless.Count);
    }
```

This works, so I'm going to run with it. I don't want to expose the ANTLR generated classes to COM, so I'm moving it all into its own assembly, which Rubberduck will reference.

It looks to me like `VBParser` is somewhat mixing abstraction levels... but is that much of an issue? Is it a good idea to "walk" the tree like this? I'm not re-parsing the code, but I'll probably end up walking it multiple times when I run code inspections, and I'll have to implement several [simple] tree listeners, to retrieve the "interesting" nodes. Is this how I'm supposed to be doing this?

Anything else strikes you as weird with this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would expect that a method of a parser which returns an `IParseTree` would be named `Parse()` instead of `startRule()` which is in addition violating the naming guidelines.

---

You should declare variables as near as possible to their usage. You could also omit the assignment of the call to `Parse()`

```
public INode Parse(string projectName, string componentName, string code)
{
    var walker = new ParseTreeWalker();                
    var listener = new VBTreeListener(projectName, componentName);

    walker.Walk(listener, Parse(code));

    return listener.Root;
}
```

---

The `VisualBasic6Parser.SubStmtContext.visibility()` method is also not going conform with the naming guidelines.

---

> Is it a good idea to "walk" the tree like this?

It is hard to say something about something one can't see.

---

> It looks to me like VBParser is somewhat mixing abstraction levels... but is that much of an issue?

It is a little bit distracting to see inside a `Parse()` method of a `VBParser` class which implements an `IRubberduckParser` interface that a `VisualBasic6Parser` class is used. But I have no idea how to solve this and if this has to be solved.

Comment: None of the ANTLR generated code follows C# casing conventions - the grammar file follows Java's and would have to be completely revisited for it to generate more C#-like methods. As for "walking" the tree, it's very ANTLR-specific (hence the [tag:antlr] tag), the *walker* isn't mine, but the `PublicSubListener` is - as the ANTLR walker walks the tree, the listener fires up these virtual methods - I couldn't have posted more code...