# Rubberduck VBA Parser, Episode VI: Return of the Abstraction

Tags: c#, parsing, rubberduck

VBA comment syntax is fun... and VBA *line continuation* makes it even more fun.

Picture a VBA module like this:

> ```
> Rem this is an old-style comment.
> ' this is a more standard comment
>
> Rem this _
>     is _
>     a _
>     multiline _
>     comment
>
> Private Sub Foo() ' this _
>                     is _
>                     also _
>                     a _
>                     multiline _
>                     comment _
>                     _
> ...don't do this at home.
>
> End Sub
>
> '@TestMethod
> Private Sub Bar()
>     ' todo: call Foo
> End Sub
> ```
>
> <sub>(no wonder syntax highlighting is getting confused!)</sub>

If you don't know what [Rubberduck](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/master/README.md) is: Rubberduck is a COM add-in for the VBE / VBA's IDE that I'm building with ...[@RubberDuck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/41243). I have a [branch](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/tree/LexicalTokens) where **I've burned the whole parser namespace** [and replaced it with ANTLR-generated code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/78722/rubberduck-vba-parser-episode-v-the-antlr-strikes-back).

The only problem is that the .g4 VB6 grammar file I'm using to generate the parser, does not support comments. So I ended up [re-]inserting an abstraction layer between ANTLR's `IParseTree` and the rest of Rubberduck.. albeit very differently this time.

I added two methods to the `IRubberduckParser` interface:

```
/// <summary>
/// Parses all code modules in specified project.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Returns an <c>IParseTree</c> for each code module in the project; the qualified module name being the key.</returns>
IEnumerable<VbModuleParseResult> Parse(VBProject vbProject);

IEnumerable<CommentNode> ParseComments(VBComponent vbComponent);
```

The `VbModuleParseResult` class encapsulates a module's `IParseTree` *and* its `CommentNode`s:

```
public class VbModuleParseResult
{
    public VbModuleParseResult(QualifiedModuleName qualifiedName, IParseTree parseTree, IEnumerable<CommentNode> comments)
    {
        _qualifiedName = qualifiedName;
        _parseTree = parseTree;
        _comments = comments;
    }

    private readonly QualifiedModuleName _qualifiedName;
    public QualifiedModuleName QualifiedName { get { return _qualifiedName; } }

    private IParseTree _parseTree;
    public IParseTree ParseTree { get { return _parseTree; } }

    private IEnumerable<CommentNode> _comments;
    public IEnumerable<CommentNode> Comments { get { return _comments; } }

}
```

That object is returned by `VBParser` methods, that the rest of Rubberduck uses (via `IRubberduckParser`):

```
public class VBParser : IRubberduckParser
{
    public INode Parse(string projectName, string componentName, string code)
    {
        var result = Parse(code);
        var walker = new ParseTreeWalker();

        var listener = new VBTreeListener(projectName, componentName);
        walker.Walk(listener, result);

        return listener.Root;
    }

    public IParseTree Parse(string code)
    {
        var input = new AntlrInputStream(code);
        var lexer = new VisualBasic6Lexer(input);
        var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        var parser = new VisualBasic6Parser(tokens);

        var result = parser.startRule();
        return result;
    }

    public IEnumerable<VbModuleParseResult> Parse(VBProject project)
    {
        return project.VBComponents.Cast<VBComponent>()
                      .Select(component => new VbModuleParseResult(new QualifiedModuleName(project.Name, component.Name), 
                                           Parse(component.CodeModule.ToString()), ParseComments(component)));
    }
```

Here we are, the `IEnumerable<CommentNode> ParseComments(VBComponent component)` implementation:

```
    public IEnumerable<CommentNode> ParseComments(VBComponent component)
    {
        var code = component.CodeModule.Code();
        var qualifiedName = new QualifiedModuleName(component.Collection.Parent.Name, component.Name);

        var commentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var continuing = false;

        var startLine = 0;
        var startColumn = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
        {
            var line = code[i];                
            var index = 0;

            if (continuing || line.HasComment(out index))
            {
                startLine = continuing ? startLine : i;
                startColumn = continuing ? startColumn : index;

                var commentLength = line.Length - index;

                continuing = line.EndsWith("_");
                if (!continuing)
                {
                    commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart());
                    var selection = new Selection(startLine + 1, startColumn + 1, i + 1, line.Length);

                    var result = new CommentNode(commentBuilder.ToString(), new QualifiedSelection(qualifiedName, selection));
                    commentBuilder.Clear();

                    yield return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    // ignore line continuations in comment text:
                    commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart()); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly:

[image: debugging session showing the parsed CommentNodes]

...but am I correct to read this last method and think there might be room for improvement? Anything else jumps at you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's tackle this piece of code, shall we?

```
public IEnumerable<CommentNode> ParseComments(VBComponent component)
{
    var code = component.CodeModule.Code();
    var qualifiedName = new QualifiedModuleName(component.Collection.Parent.Name, component.Name);

    var commentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var continuing = false;

    var startLine = 0;
    var startColumn = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
    {
        var line = code[i];                
        var index = 0;

        if (continuing || line.HasComment(out index))
        {
            startLine = continuing ? startLine : i;
            startColumn = continuing ? startColumn : index;

            var commentLength = line.Length - index;

            continuing = line.EndsWith("_");
            if (!continuing)
            {
                commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart());
                var selection = new Selection(startLine + 1, startColumn + 1, i + 1, line.Length);

                var result = new CommentNode(commentBuilder.ToString(), new QualifiedSelection(qualifiedName, selection));
                commentBuilder.Clear();

                yield return result;
            }
            else
            {
                // ignore line continuations in comment text:
                commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart()); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alright, first thing I see is some duplication:

```
continuing = line.EndsWith("_");
if (!continuing)
{
    commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart());
    var selection = new Selection(startLine + 1, startColumn + 1, i + 1, line.Length);

    var result = new CommentNode(commentBuilder.ToString(), new QualifiedSelection(qualifiedName, selection));
    commentBuilder.Clear();

    yield return result;
}
else
{
    // ignore line continuations in comment text:
    commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart()); 
}
```

`commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart());` is duplicated.

So lets remove it.

```
continuing = line.EndsWith("_");
commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart());
if (!continuing)
{
    var selection = new Selection(startLine + 1, startColumn + 1, i + 1, line.Length);

    var result = new CommentNode(commentBuilder.ToString(), new QualifiedSelection(qualifiedName, selection));
    commentBuilder.Clear();

    yield return result;
}
```

Additionally, there's some duplication here...

```
if (continuing || line.HasComment(out index))
{
    startLine = continuing ? startLine : i;
    startColumn = continuing ? startColumn : index;

    var commentLength = line.Length - index;

    continuing = line.EndsWith("_");
    commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart());
    if (!continuing)
    {
        var selection = new Selection(startLine + 1, startColumn + 1, i + 1, line.Length);

        var result = new CommentNode(commentBuilder.ToString(), new QualifiedSelection(qualifiedName, selection));
        commentBuilder.Clear();

        yield return result;
    }
}
```

`continuing` is checked three times between changes. That's a bit of a waste.

Maybe we can fix it?

```
if (continuing || line.HasComment(out index))
{
    if(!continuing){
        startLine = i;
        startColumn = index;
    }
    var commentLength = line.Length - index;

    continuing = line.EndsWith("_");
    commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart());
    if (!continuing)
    {
        var selection = new Selection(startLine + 1, startColumn + 1, i + 1, line.Length);

        var result = new CommentNode(commentBuilder.ToString(), new QualifiedSelection(qualifiedName, selection));
        commentBuilder.Clear();

        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Hmm, we're still checking it twice... and  `if (a || b) { if(!a)` structures are messy. I wonder if there's something we can do about that?

Invert it, maybe? (if `A OR B` is true then `NOT A` implies `B`)

```
if (continuing || line.HasComment(out index))
{
    if(line.HasComment(out index)){
        startLine = i;
        startColumn = index;
    }
```

Hmm...
Here's a batshit crazy idea.

Put a for loop inside the current for loop to repeat the bits you need.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
    {
        var line = code[i];                
        var index = 0;

        if (line.HasComment(out index))
        {
            startLine = i;
            startColumn = index;

            //multiline comment forloop...
            for (; i < code.Length; i++)
            {
                line = code[i];
                var commentLength = line.Length - index;
                commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart());
                if(!line.EndsWith("_"))
                {
                   break;
                }
            }
            var selection = new Selection(startLine + 1, startColumn + 1, i + 1, line.Length);

            var result = new CommentNode(commentBuilder.ToString(), new QualifiedSelection(qualifiedName, selection));
            commentBuilder.Clear();

            yield return result;
        }
    }
```

Yep, it works! * Mad programmer cackle *

You can even move this section

```
            for (; i < code.Length; i++)
            {
                line = code[i];
                var commentLength = line.Length - index;
                commentBuilder.Append(line.Substring(index, commentLength).TrimStart());
                if(!line.EndsWith("_"))
                {
                   break;
                }
            }
```

to a new function:

```
private int appendComment(code, lineNumber, commentBuilder, commentColumn)
```

But it takes... 4 arguments. So that's maybe not ideal.

### New bugs ... err, features

There's one sideeffect:

Previously, if input was

```
' This is a file with a single line that claims to contain a multiline comment _
```

You would ignore it.

Now, it will make a new selection instead, which supposedly ends at `code.Length + 1`. So past EOF. This can be a feature ("Your comment goes past EOF!") or something that will break some asserts.

Comment: About the "bug": the line that immediately follows a comment that ends with an underscore, is also a comment, regardless of its content. As for the comment+underline+EOF, that's not something that is possible in VBA - I tried very hard to test it: the VBE automatically adds a new line (the continued comment) under it, and *another* new line under that (the properly terminated line of code). Conclusion: there is no such bug; importing a code file that would have been edited as such (say, in Notepad) to force it, results in **the VBE itself** ignoring the EOF-comment.

Comment: Also the `+1` in `code.Length + 1` is because line and column numbers in the VBE object model are 1-based: that `+1` makes the `Selection` readily usable.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer 1: I'm the other dev working on the project.
Disclaimer 2: This will be more of a pie in the sky design review than code review.

---

## Co-dev Hat

***It works***, so I don't really care how it's implemented. (At least until I actually have to make some kind of change to it. Gods help me that may I never have to truly understand your parser. Not because it's bad, but because I haven't spent any time learning it.)

## Reviewer Hat

I would expect the `CommendNode`s to be part of the `ParseTree`. I understand why they're not. The grammar file you borrowed from another Open Source project didn't include comments. This is because that project was interested in *executing* VBA code. Therefore it, naturally, excluded them. Our project is different. We're interested in *analyzing* the code and this includes the comments. I feel like the technically *right* thing to do would be to modify the grammar file so that comments are parsed along with the rest of the language. At that point, implementing features based off of parsed comments becomes identical to implementing any other feature based off of parsed code. As it is, any features that need to know about both the code **and** the comments is likely to need special handling for each. That's double the work and double the chance to introduce a bug.

Now, is that worth the effort? I don't know yet. I haven't tried to modify the grammar file to pick up comments yet.

Comment: +1 you're right - this is just a huge work-around, to work with the .g4 grammar without spending the time & effort to tweak it to support comments. FWIW I *did* try to modify the grammar file, but it would pick up comments under an *ErrorNode*... if that's the best I can get, I like the work-around better.